# Check if element exists or is a null

Tags: c#

I have object structure like this:

```
List.data[0].Contact.Mobile.MobileNumber
```

And I need to check if `MobileNumber` is null.
problem is that also `Contact and Mobile` can be null also.

Is there any better/easier/cleaner way than something like this:

```
(List.data[0].Contact!=null && List.data[0].Contact.Mobile!=null && List.data[0].Mobile.MobileNumber!=null)
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in C#6 you can try this

```
var exists = List.data[0].Contact?.Mobile?.MobileNumber != null;
```

Comment: shouldn't that be != ?

Comment: thx  Can you maybe tell me what in case that eg. mobile is a list? Mobile[0]? seems not to be working

Comment: @szpic What does this `Mobile` list contain? What data type?

Comment: @szpic use `Modile.FirstOrDefault()?.MobileNumber`